# Is there any solution for overlapping markers in Leaflet as CommonJS module?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to find solution for overlapping markers issue in Leaflet which may be used as a usual CommonJS module.

There are several solutions already:

1. [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet)
2. [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

However they both assume that Leaflet is using as a global thing. Do you know any other options?

Comment: Probably worth contributing by reviving [Leaflet.markercluster PR #445](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/pull/445)! :-)

Comment: This is two year old PR which was closed a year ago, don't think they need any reviewing.

Comment: It is totally up to you to decide whether you want to contribute or not, be it in your own interest or not.